# Event not unsubscribing

Tags: c#

The event is not being unsubscribed I don't know why and it kills me...
I have a pause button that works using the same idea of              CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent; it is called but doesn't seem to stop it...

My code:

```
    private EventHandler RenderingEvent;

    StopSimulation(sender, t);// how i am calling it

    private void StopSimulation(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        time = DateTime.Now;
        int removedtime = 0;
        InSimulation = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent; // doesnt seem to stop it
    }


    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent;
        position = new Point(5, HighestPoint * MetresPerPixel);
        //acceleration = new Vector(0, 30); // y direction is downwards
        int removedtime = 0;
        time = DateTime.Now;
        RenderingEvent = (s, g) => OnRendering(s, g, removedtime, time);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += RenderingEvent;
        btn_Pause.Content = "Pause";
    }
```

My "complete" code (removed all the garbage)

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       using System.Windows;
       using System.Windows.Controls;
       using System.Windows.Data;
       using System.Windows.Documents;
       using System.Windows.Input;
       using System.Windows.Media;
       using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
       using System.Windows.Navigation;
       using System.Windows.Shapes;
       using System.Threading;
       using System.Timers;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
       using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
       namespace WpfApplication3
       {
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    bool LabelExist = false;
    int count = 1;
    bool InSimulation = false;
    bool ModelModeAsParticle;
    static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Point position; // in pixels
    private Vector Velocity; // in pixels per second
    private Vector acceleration; // in pixels per square second
    private DateTime time;
    private EventHandler RenderingEvent;
    private System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler TimerEvent;
    private double TimeConstant;
    private double TimersTime;
    private double MetresPerPixel;
    double HighestPoint, LowestPoint;
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent;
        position = new Point(5, HighestPoint * MetresPerPixel);
        //acceleration = new Vector(0, 30); // y direction is downwards
        int removedtime = 0;
        time = DateTime.Now;
        RenderingEvent = (s, g) => OnRendering(s, g, removedtime, time);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += RenderingEvent;
        btn_Pause.Content = "Pause";
    }
    private void OnRendering(object sender, EventArgs g, int removedtime, DateTime t)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-removedtime);
        var dt = (now - t).TotalSeconds;
        time = now;
        position += Velocity * dt;
        Velocity += acceleration * dt;
        projectileGeometry.Center = position;
    }
    void LoadStaticsAndStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormatCheck(txtb_AngleOLaunch) == false || FormatCheck(txtbox_InitialVelocity) == false || FormatCheck(txtbox_TimeOfFlight) == false)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            MPP(newParticle, newEnvironment);
            OnLoaded(this, e);
            double HVelTemp = newParticle.InitialVelocity.HorizontalVelocity * MetresPerPixel;
            double VVelTemp = newParticle.InitialVelocity.VerticalVelocity * MetresPerPixel * -1;
            Velocity = new Vector(HVelTemp, VVelTemp); // y direction is downwards
            acceleration = new Vector(0, -1*newEnvironment.gravity*MetresPerPixel); // y direction is downwards
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(200);
            TimerEvent = (s, t) => onTimedEvent(s, t, newParticle, newEnvironment);
            aTimer.Elapsed += TimerEvent;
            InSimulation = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    int DigitAccuracy = 2;
    void onTimedEvent(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs t, particle newProjectile, Environment newEnvironment)
    {
        if (newProjectile.Time < newProjectile.TimeOfFlight && InSimulation == true)
        {
        newProjectile.Time = Math.Round(TimersTime,1);
        }
        else if (newProjectile.TimeOfFlight == newProjectile.Time)
        {
            StopSimulation(sender, t);
        }
    }
    private void StopSimulation(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        InSimulation = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent;
    }
    private void btn_Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)btn_Pause.Content == "Pause")
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent;
        }
        else if (InSimulation == true && (string)btn_Pause.Content != "Pause")
        {
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            RenderingEvent = (s, g) => OnRendering(s, g, removedtime, time);
            CompositionTarget.Rendering += RenderingEvent;
        }
        else if (InSimulation != true)
        {
        }
    }
    private void btn_fastforward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InSimulation == true)
        {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent;
        RenderingEvent = (s, g) => OnRendering(s, g, removedtime, time);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += RenderingEvent;
        }
        else if (InSimulation == false)
        {
        }
    }
    private void btn_backwards_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InSimulation == true)
        {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= RenderingEvent;
        RenderingEvent = (s, g) => OnRendering(s, g, removedtime, time);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += RenderingEvent;
        }
        else if (InSimulation == false)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Is OnLoaded called before you call StopSimulation()? Why are you using a field for the event handler? Write a private method for that.

Comment: @helb yes it is, i have a pause button working but doesnt seem to work for StopSimulation

Comment: @JonSkeet what should i show?

Comment: As I said, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Ideally a console app. Something we can copy, paste, compile, run. Describe what you see vs what you expect to see.

Comment: there is going to be alot of code

Comment: Set breakpoints on each `+= RenderingEvent` (and `-=`) and carefully debug. You are definitely having mistake in your code somewhere. If you suspect .net framework, compiler, etc. then try to reproduce problem and if you succeed - present minimum code example needed to reproduce the problem. Another possibility: post complete code here, but remove everything except subscribing/unsubscribing to that event, so we can guess what you doing wrong. Currently code sample is incomplete and *garbaged* (contains unrelated stuff), which is usually a subject to close question as offtopic.

Comment: I agree with @helb. Using a lambda for an event handler is likely to cause issues even if you are sitting it to a field. Also, have you tried writing debug print statements to see when the different register/unregister methods are being called (using breakpoints or Console.WriteLine)? And what JonSkeet is saying (I think) is that we don't see the code that sets up your pause button.

Comment: Could be the same problem as this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1056344/handler-not-removed-from-event-when-routed-through-a-proxy

Comment: You seem to be removing the event handler, but when you do are you also stopping the current render in progress? I am assuming you are also calling these from separate threads.

Comment: @Sinatr I've added more code, wasnt sure what you mean by garbage :/

Comment: @JimmyV im not using multiple threads but what do you mean by stopping the current render?

Comment: @NextInLine added the code for the pause button

Comment: You could just make your life so much easier and attach the event once and never remove it.  Store the `time` as a field, rather than the handler, and when the handler fires check the current state to see if it should actually do anything or not.  It would likely make the program a *lot* simpler.

Comment: @Servy tbh i havent played with events before so its abit new to me sorry :/ but didnt i store time as a field?

Comment: @ObnoxiousFrog Then why are you going through so much effort just to close over that field for your handler?  If you've already done that, it makes always having a single handler assigned and never removing it be that much easier.

Comment: @Servy how would you advice i do that?

Comment: [I already told you how.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193305/event-not-unsubscribing?noredirect=1#comment44766166_28193305).

Comment: In `btn_Pause_Click` you have some condition, which may (?) cause event to be subscribed twice without unsubscribing. When I say *garbaged*, I mean there is a lot of things which out of scope of your problem and can be easily omitted (to example, `using` in full peace), I understand, what based on debugging experience it may be non-trivial task to decide what to remove, but still, *noise* in snippets distracting too much. Generally speaking, your event handling is a bit weird. You should set lambda once and then only use `-=`/`+=`. Use @Jeb answer to debug. Or change approach as @Servy say.

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose, perhaps create a new event which effectively wraps your CompositionTarget.RenderingEvent event, except when attaching/detaching:

```
private int _eventSubscriptionCount = 0;
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> RenderingEventWrapper
{
    add
    {
        CompositionTarget.RenderingEvent += value;
        _eventSubscriptionCount++;
    }
    remove
    {
        CompositionTarget.RenderingEvent -= value;
        _eventSubscriptionCount--;
    }
}
```

Then see how many are still subscribed when you are expecting to have no more subscriptions... Debugging the add/remove parts will do the trick also and inspecting the call stack when execution break occurs.